# TypeORM - Get every related Entity

Tags: typescript, typeorm

The Problem I am facing is, that I have a table called permissions, which holds an ID as a primary key and a user, a survey and a role as foreign keys. I need a way of filtering these permissions on a per user/survey basis. For example getting associated the role of that permission entry for user x on survey y. The relations are set up in the following way:

Permission:

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.permissions)
user: User

@ManyToOne(() => Survey, (survey) => survey.permissions)
survey: Survey

@ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.permissions)
role: Role
```

User, Role and Survey:

```
@OneToMany(() => Permission, (permission) => permission.user/role/survey)
permissions: Permission[]
```

When filtering like this

```
const permission = await Permission.findOneBy({
    user: user,
    survey: survey,
});
```

It does give me the right permission entry, unfortunately only the ID of that permission. So the value of `permission` looks like this:

```
{ id: 1 }
```

Is there a way to get every other field as well? I am mainly focussed on the role id since that is what i need to determine the user's actual permissions but some extra information would be nice to filter for every user with a specific role inside a given survey for example. Ideally something like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    user: <user>,
    survey: <survey>,
    role: <role>
}
```

Edit:
I found a way to achieve what i was looking for... kind of. By doing it like this:

```
const permission = await Permission.findOneBy({
    user: user,
    survey: survey,
});

const role = await Role.findOneBy({
    permission: permission,
});
```

I can effectively isolate the specific role with all the information I need. But a more elegant way in my opinion would be to just call `permission.role.<attribute>` to get what i need to know. Is there any to to do it like that?